# Text color not changing correctly during export in Adobe Photoshop script

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I am trying to create a script that changes the color of the text in the active layer to black, exports it as a PNG file with the specified name, then changes the color of the text to white and exports it again as a PNG file with the specified name, and repeats the same process with different colors (pink, blue, green, red) and saves them as PNG files with different names. The script is exporting the files correctly, but all of the files are being exported as black and not in the respective colors. I have tried adding =null before recoloring but the activeLayer cannot be equal to null or undefined. Can someone please help me figure out why my script is not working as intended and how I can fix it?

Here is the code:

````
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = new SolidColor();
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color.rgb.hexValue = "000000";

var textLayerName = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.name;

var newName = prompt("Enter a new name for the export", "black_" + textLayerName);

var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
exportOptions.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
exportOptions.quality = 100;
var file = new File("black " + newName + ".png");
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(file, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, exportOptions);

app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = new SolidColor();
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color.rgb.hexValue = "FFFFFF";


var file2 = new File("white " + newName + ".png");
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(file2, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, exportOptions);

app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = new SolidColor();
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color.rgb.hexValue = "fc82d8";


var file3 = new File("pink " + newName + ".png");
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(file3, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, exportOptions);

app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = new SolidColor();
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color.rgb.hexValue = "63a8e7";


var file4 = new File("blue " + newName + ".png");
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(file4, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, exportOptions);

app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = new SolidColor();
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color.rgb.hexValue = "0c6a27";


var file5 = new File("green " + newName + ".png");
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(file5, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, exportOptions);

app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = new SolidColor();
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color.rgb.hexValue = "a80000";


var file6 = new File("red " + newName + ".png");
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(file6, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, exportOptions);```
````

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I don't think you can declare a text color as a new solid colour directly

You have to do it in this format:

```
var textColor = new SolidColor();
textColor.rgb.hexValue = "fc82d8";
app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = textColor;
```

It also helps if you declare a variable as the active document

```
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
```

Saves you typing out "app.activeDocument" each time :)

I think you've got your colours mixed up - the last one listed is a red colour but given the name "green".

As you're doing a repetitive task, it's easier to do it in a loop:

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; // OFF

var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var textLayerName = srcDoc.activeLayer.name;

var newName = prompt("Enter a new name for the export", "black_" + textLayerName);

var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
exportOptions.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
exportOptions.quality = 100;

var colours = [
["000000", "black" ],
["FFFFFF", "white" ],
["FC82D8", "pink"], 
["63A8E7", "blue"], 
["007236", "green"], // change this colour
["A80000", "red"], 
 ]

var textColor = new SolidColor();

for (var i = 0; i < colours.length; i++)
{
   var col = colours[i][1];
   textColor.rgb.hexValue = colours[i][0];
   app.activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem.color = textColor
   // a space is added to the filename here
   var file = new File(col + newName + " .png");
   srcDoc.exportDocument(file, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, exportOptions);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks I've modified the script respectivly and now color Black, Blue, Green and Red are exported correctly. However white (which comes right after black) is exported as light blue and the pink file (which comes after white) is exported as the same color of the blue file. I would insert the code here but it says its too long to comment

Comment: The trick is to re-edit your post, change the code, and mention what you've updated.